# Staticfile issue when trying to deploy django

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

I am trying to deploy Django following [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/10/16/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-7.html#version-control) tutorial but am getting an error. When the tutorial says to run `python manage.py collectstatic`, instead of collectstatic running without further prompt as suggested, I get the following:

```
/home/elections/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)

You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings.

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
```

I entered Yes and got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/elections/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/elections/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/elections/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/elections/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/elections/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 199, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/home/elections/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 124, in collect
    handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
  File "/home/elections/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 354, in copy_file
    if not self.delete_file(path, prefixed_path, source_storage):
  File "/home/elections/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 260, in delete_file
    if self.storage.exists(prefixed_path):
  File "/home/elections/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 392, in exists
    return os.path.exists(self.path(name))
  File "/home/elections/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 50, in path
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("You're using the staticfiles app "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.
```

What could have made this happen differently from the tutorial, and how do I fix this error?

Comment: as it clearly state you have to set STATIC_ROOT path in your `settings.py`

Comment: @SumeetKumar The tutorial says "This command copy all the static assets to an external directory where NGINX can serve the files for us". Do you know what I should set STATIC_ROOT to?

Comment: If you are setting up with nginx then you might need to check your nginx conf file and add alias for static path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned you need to define the [`STATIC_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT) variable in your `settings.py` in order to make [`collectstatic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic) work.

> The absolute path to the directory where collectstatic will collect
>   static files for deployment.
>   Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"

You may want to define [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS) too.

---

The [`nginx.conf`](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/10/16/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-7.html#configuring-nginx) from the tutorial you have posted expects to serve your collected static files from `/home/boards/staticfiles/`. Since the tutorial deploys everything on a single, monolithic server which hosts the database (`postgres`), web server (`nginx`) and the application (`django`) you can set it as follows:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/boards/staticfiles/'
```